# How to select after put in Saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { action_creators } from './redux';

class App extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return [
            <div>{this.props.number}</div>,
            <button type="button" onClick={() => this.props.set_number_async({ number:10 })}>increase_number_async</button>
        ]
    }
}

function map_state_to_props(state) {
    return {
        number: state.number;
    }
}

function map_dispatch_to_props(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        set_number_async: action_creators.get_action_of_set_number_async
    }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(map_state_to_props, map_dispatch_to_props)(App);
```

Redux

```
import { Action, createAction, handleActions } from 'redux-actions';
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';
import { all, put, select, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export const action_creators = {
    get_action_of_set_number: createAction<{ number:number }>('set_number'),
    get_action_of_set_number_async: createAction<{ number:number }>('set_number_async'),
    get_action_of_set_number_async2: createAction<{ number: number }>('set_number_async2')
};

const state = {
    number: 0
}

function* set_number_async(action: Action<{ number:number }>) {
    let state = yield select((state) => state.number);

    console.log('first', state); // 0

    yield delay(1000);
    yield put(action_creators.get_action_of_set_number_async2(action.payload!));

    state = yield select((state) => state.number);

    console.log('second', state); // 0
}

function* set_number_async2(action: Action<{ number: number }>) {
    yield put(action_creators.get_action_of_set_number(action.payload!));
}

export function* saga() {
    yield all([
        takeEvery('set_number_async', set_number_async),
        takeEvery('set_number_async2', set_number_async2)
    ]);
}

export default handleActions({
    set_number: (state, action) => {
        const new_number = action.payload!.number;
        return { ...state, number:new_number };
    }
}, state);
```

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/q441ylnn9)

I expected that 10 was printed by second console.log() when I click a button, but 0 was printed.

What did I do worng? I tried to find it out in a tutorial, but I didn't get a solution.

I want to know how to re-select new state dispatched.

please could you help me? Thansk for reading. :)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I wrote example URL without saving. It got fixed.

Comment: when you yield "put", the execution of saga goes further without waiting for the action to be completed. So when you read the store again it is not updated yet. You need to use "take" after that, which will wait for some specific action that will be dispatched after the store is updated

Comment: @Vladimir Yeah! I see. You mean https://codesandbox.io/s/wyk0k5y4o7, right? Thanks :D

Comment: yes, something like that, because "put" is non-blocking, and "take" stops execution until it receives the action.

Comment: @Vladimir Thank you for your kindness. :)